# How to get Config value in PDF magetno 2

Tags: invoice, core-config-data

how do you get config value in model class i am doing a override for PDF INVOICE by `<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"` but i am not able to get the config value

```
const COMPANY_ADDRESS = 'module_name/general/address';

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

}
public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
    );
}

public function getAddress($storeId = null)
{
    return $this->getConfigValue(self::COMPANY_ADDRESS, $storeId);
}
```

In invoice class
instead calling this `$this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());`
i wantto call my config `getAddress`

Comment: Which config value you want here?

Comment: i created a custom config for store address
and only this working for me $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore()); which is the default one from core file

Comment: Okay understood, you want Store Configuration value here in your Model file, Am I right ?

Comment: yes that is correct, i have helper class but i am not able to see the results

Comment: can you please update your question with your helper function here ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. After adding store configuration, did you clear the cache ?

Comment: Ya when i pass getAddress i get nothing my address is empty soon as i put it back to normal it picks up the default value

Comment: Can you please check your config path is correct ?

Comment: it saves in DB i copied that path

Comment: Okay, Can you please try to get that config value from another file once ? Or instead of using this function in Model you can create Helper and move that function there.

Comment: using helper to move it to model

Comment: Can you please try another config key once ? Are you able to get base url with that function there?

Comment: I have checked other config it works
this config was type="textarea"

Comment: Can you please set value in bank transfer payment method's instruction first in config and try to get that value using your function ? Because there is also textarea type. So you can get better idea what is the issue ?

Comment: $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
only this works